# Dynamic PHP Dropdown Menu for Countries

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, drop-down-menu

Okay so I have a table called Countries and it looks like this:

```
---------------------------
|Country      |    Code   |
---------------------------
|Afganastan   |     AF    |
|ÅLAND ISLANDS|     AX    |
|  etc.       |     etc.  |
---------------------------
```

The thing that I want to do is create a dynamic menu in which the user chooses a country and that itself gets stored as a value that I can call after the user hits submit.

I did try something here but I'm not sure what its doing because I am still new to PHP and HTML to the point where I just type things in to see what would happen.

Anyways I am really stuck and I tried using google and the search feature in this site and nothing I found worked for me...

The code I tried is this:

```
<select>
    <?php
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT Country FROM Countries');

        echo '<select name="country">';

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }

        echo '</select>';
    ?>

   </select>
```

The result is supposed to look like a dropdown menu with the list of countries from the database in it. But this doesn't work and just shows this in the drop down:

```
.$row['name']
```

Which is nothing close to what I want because that's not even a country. when I remove that part of the code, then there is no option for the user to choose, the menu is empty.

**EDIT**
My code so far that still doesn't work:

```
<select name = 'country'>
    <?php

    include ("account.php");
    include ("connect.php");

        $result = mysql_query('SELECT Code , Country FROM Countries');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row['Code']?>"><?php echo $row['Country']?></option>

            <?php}

    ?>

   </select>
```

The `include ("account.php");` and `include ("connect.php");` lines allow me to connect to my database.

Comment: `var_dump($result)`? And also, why do you have two `<select>`?

Comment: Did you make sure there is any record in the table. Code is perfect and it mustn't produce any error

Comment: My database has 200+ different countries and their Code in the Countries table. I imported them myself from a text file.

Answer (score 1):

you code should be something like this

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "yourpassword";
$db   = "databasename";

// This part sets up the connection to the 
// database (so you don't need to reopen the connection
// again on the same page).
$ms = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if ( !$ms )
{
echo "Error connecting to database.\n";
}

// Then you need to make sure the database you want
// is selected.
@mysql_select_db($db);


<form method = "POST" action = "abc.php">
<select name = 'country'>
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id , name FROM Countries');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['name']?></option>
    <?php}
?>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

Now in php use this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
```

And you will see what user selected. Check your settings there might be some problem.

Comment: the thing is that my dropdown menu has nothing in it for the user to choose. How do i throw in stuff from the database for the user to pick from?

Comment: yea I did that but nothing changed. I still get an empty drop down menu.

Comment: SELECT Code , Country from Countries; And in loop $row['Code'] and $row['Country']. These are necessary

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <?php
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Countries');
?>
<select name="country">
<?php 

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
<?php
        }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your single and double quotes are messing you up:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
```

should be:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
```

You can use a single quote around your script but when you jump out of it to do the `$row['id']` and `$row['name']` you are running into issues because it thinks you are jumping back into your quoted code... Either use my example above, starting/ending with double-quotes and escaping all double-quotes inside that need to display, or escape your single quotes in the `$row[\'id\']` and `$row[\'name\']`

Thant should help you out.

Comment: And if your table looks exactly like above, then there is no `id` or `name` fields that you are trying to call, only `Country` and `Code`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your table doesn't have a column **id**. Try changing your query like

```
SELECT Country, Code FROM Countries
```

Then the code and the html should be like this

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";  //username
$pass = "pass";  //password
$db   = "db";    //database

$con = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if ( !$con )
{
echo "Error connecting to database.\n";
}

@mysql_select_db($db);
?>

<select name="country">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Choose..</option>
<?php
//echo '<select name = \'country\'>';

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT Country, Code FROM Countries');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo '<option value="'.$row['Code'].'">'.$row['Country'].'</option>';
    }

?>
</select>
```

Comment: sorry, it still didn't work. Please take a look at my edit to see what I have so far based on everyone's answers.

Comment: Whats the error on my code can you write it? I mean is there an error or nothing ?

Comment: I don't see an error in your code, I just don't see my drop down menu having anything in it.

Comment: If you tahe an error like **Parse error: syntax error,** then you should change this one <?php}  to this  <?php }   Need some space

Answer (score 0):

```
  <select>
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT Country FROM Countries');

    echo '<select name="country">';
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
    for ($i=0; $i<count($row ); $i++)
    {
       echo '<option value="'.$row[$i]['id'].'">'.$row[$i]['name'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
?>
```

next page use print_r($_POST);
or var_dump($_REQUEST);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) you can use either the field names or their selected index to read them from the fetched row. You can also use either the [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) functions to merge content into a string to help keep the HTML fragment clean of the quotes needed to merge in values otherwise.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT Country, Code FROM Countries');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   printf('<option value="%1$s">%2$s</option>',
            $row['Code'], $row['Country']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement selected only 'Country' from the 'Countries' table; as a result, it's impossible for  you to use $row['id'] and $row['name']. 
Use this instead:

```
    echo '<select name="country">';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo '<option value="'.$row['Code'].'">'.$row['Country'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
?>
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: What is it giving you? That should work. Right inside the while loop, put var_dump($result); what did it give you?

Comment: Ok; first, you shouldn't wrap 2 select statements inside each other; remove the outer select statement, run the code I gave you earlier (the 'var_dump' one), and let me know what it gives you again

Comment: Alright; we are having a head way. Now, try this. For the select statement itself, try this: select Country, Code from Countries;  let me know if that works: it should work.

Comment: Did that work? It should work if the data you posted in the question is valid. If it didn't work, try the select statement using PHPMyAdmin, and see if it produces the result you wanted.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I tried it in PhpMyAdmin and it did show the data so then I copied that statement into my code and it made no difference to the page.

Comment: Paste your entire code into this URL, http://codepad.viper-7.com/, and post on here the link that URL generates for you. I need to take a look at the whole code, as there's probably something going on that is breaking your code.

Comment: I couldn't get the site to open so I posted the entire thing on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iYja5DHR)

Comment: Ok. 2 things: in the select statement, change 'CODE' to 'Code' so that it matches the table (that shouldn't be the issue, but just in case); second, copy the part of the code in the connect.php where the connection to the db was made (don't include the actual username/passwords, but ensure that they were valid for the db)

Comment: I am using the same connect.php file for some of my other websites and they still work so I don't think thats the issue, and I changed CODE to Code --> no change :(

Comment: When you did 'var_dump($result)', what did it output to the browser?

Comment: my bad......change it to var_dump($row), not $result; if you are actually receiving a response from the db, it should show you all the rows retrieved from the db for both columns

Comment: what is it dumping once again on the screen '.$row['Country'].'?

Comment: ok.....we are going to try a few more options; I'm suspecting that the problem might have to do with the connection; anyway, try the code in this link http://pastebin.com/dhRy7Zgn . Let me know what it outputs. If that doesn't work, you have a problem with the connection.

Comment: This is my connect.php --> http://pastebin.com/FunACKLx

This is my screenshot --> http://tinypic.com/r/rm8cg4/6

Comment: the problem isn't in that code; it's somewhere else. Look at the code in this link, http://pastebin.com/peb7Xiah, and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Please stop with the rolling debug session.  Stack Overflow is not your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem I was having. The first being that there was an extra select tag in the page and the second that the file was saved as a html page instead of a php file. Thank you to everyone that helped me figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Try my code, I'm using this and it really works... just change the values...

```
<?php
    include ('connect.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM casestatusfile";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<select name = 'txtCaseStatus'/>";
    echo "<option value = ''>--- Select ---</option>";
    $casestatus = $_POST['txtCaseStatus'];
    $selected = 'selected = "selected" ';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option " .($row['CASESTATUSCODE'] == $casestatus? $selected:''). "value='". $row['CASESTATUSCODE'] ."'>" . $row['CASESTATUS'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

I'm sure that is working because that is the one that i'm using....